# Remove XML attribute based on value

Tags: sql, sqlxml

I have an XML variable with only one element in it. I need to check if this element has a particular attribute, and if it does, i need to check if that attribute has a specific value, and if it does, i need to remove that attribute from the XML element.

So lets say I have

```
DECLARE @Xml XML
SET @XML = 
'<person
    FirstName="Harvey"
    LastName="Saayman"
    MobileNumber="Empty"
/>'
```

The MobileNumber attribute may or may not be there, if it is, and the value is "Empty", i need to change my XML variable to this:

```
'<person
    FirstName="Harvey"
    LastName="Saayman"
/>'
```

I'm a complete SQL XML noob and have no idea how to go about this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modify() DML clause to modify the XML nodes. On this case something like:

```
SET @XML.modify('delete (/person/@MobileNumber)[1]')
```

[This XML workshop](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/xml-data-modification-language-workbench/) can be helpfull to have a deeper understanding of the DML clauses delete, insert, replace, etc.

Comment: I know it is an old post but worth updating if things are wrong. I'm confused, wouldn't the suggested answer delete the attribute anyway not only if `MobileNumber` is `Empty`? The requester says "The MobileNumber attribute may or may not be there, if it is, and the value is "Empty", i need to change my XML ...", I don't think this is the correct answer then.

Comment: Easy peasy @GiuseppeRomagnuolo post the answer you think is right. Or upvote the one from Mikael.

Comment: Hi @Yaroslav, my suggestion was more for you to update your answer if you also agreed it is actually misleading. Despite a few years have passed now, there might still be folks struggling with the same issue; your answer, being the accepted one will come up first and be misleading I believe, that's all. I have voted Mikael up but I haven't voted yours down yet :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @XML.modify('delete /person/@MobileNumber[. = "Empty"]')
```